# How to get CPU statistics PER PROCESSOR on AIX without requiring root privileges?

Tags: cpu, aix, statistics, sar

I want to get the per processor statistics for my AIX machines. I can use the ‘**sar -P ALL 1 1**’ ([Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=s-sar-command#sar__row-d3e4315)) command but it requires root privileges.
[image]

Is there a command that can give me PER PROCESSOR statistics **without requiring root privileges**?

P.S. : I explored **lparstat** but it does not give PER PROCESSOR statistics.

Comment: You can use sudo for sar command, I think...

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't explained which information exactly you are after, i can only point you in a general direction.

Read the man page of the `mpstat` command, which should do what you want to achieve. Basically it gives you utilisation metrics for the "logical processors" in the system. Depending on the hardware you use (Power7, Power8, Power9, Power10), the way the "managed system" is operated (IVM, HMC, ...) you will have to interpret the output of the command.

Note that you also may need to evaluate the hypervisor statistics and other data for a complete picture.

Also notice that the tunables in `/etc/tunables/nextboot` may highly influence your metrics and you need to take them into account.

No offense, but you don't come across like being able to analyse complex performance data of a modern, highly virtualized IBM system. I suggest getting some expert for the job.